# How to prevent VSCode to load powershell profile?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I have looked at VSCode settings, I can't see clearly what "integrated" means that's what I have but it loads external powershell profile. I want to prevent it to do so, is it possible ?

P.S. : I don't have and don't want powershell extensions, should I to have this option ?

Update: As suggested I have unchecked "powershell.enableProfileLoading" both in User and Workspace settings, relaunched vscode, but in terminal still gets "Loading personal and system profiles took" weirdly it still doesn't work for me ?

Is it possible this is a VSCode settings bug ?

Comment: `"powershell.enableProfileLoading": false` on your settings.json

Comment: I have unchecked both in User and Workspace settings, relaunched vscode, but in terminal still gets "Loading personal and system profiles took" weird ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **If you DO have Visual Studio Code's [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) installed** and you want to **suppress loading of profiles in its special-purpose shell, the *PowerShell Integrated Console* (PIC)**:

  - GUI option: Via the Settings dialog, *uncheck* the option `PowerShell: Enable Profile Loading`
  - `Settings.json` file option: As [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) states, add the following setting:

    - `"powershell.enableProfileLoading": false`
- **If you do NOT have the PowerShell extension installed OR you (also) want to control profile loading for *general-purpose* PowerShell sessions** running in Visual Studio's integrated terminal:

  - In the Settings dialog, search for `terminal profiles` and click on the `Edit in settings.json` link next to the platform-appropriate `Terminal › Integrated › Profiles: <os>` entry, where `<os>` is one of `windows`, `linux` or `osx` (macOS).
  - This will open your `Settings.json` file for editing and either create or navigate to a preexisting `"terminal.integrated.profiles.<os>"`object, which contains the profiles of all shells available in the integrated terminal.
  - Locate the PowerShell profile and add an `"args": [ "-noprofile" ]` property in order to suppress profile loading, which passes the `-noprofile` parameter to the PowerShell CLI ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7+) on startup; e.g., on *Windows*:

```json
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell",
            "args": [ "-noprofile" ]
        },
        // ...
}
```